# What happens if I visit a site that supports HSTS and I clear the cookies, cache, etc from my browser?

Tags: history, browser-cache

Would this mean that I could potentially be susceptible to a man in the middle attack? Would the browser need to cache this information again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes, assuming you initially try to access the site through HTTP. If you initially try to access the site through HTTPS, it will automatically and immediately re-establish HSTS.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of `initially`?

Comment: By "initially", I mean your first access to the site after having cleared things. It can either by clicking on a link on another web page, a bookmark, or entering the site name in the URL bar manually.